# which RPM provides the file resolv.conf in Centos 6

Tags: centos, resolv.conf

Which RPM provides the file resolv.conf in Centos 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy to discover. Just run:

```
rpm -qf /etc/resolv.conf
```

You will see the answer is:

```
file /etc/resolv.conf is not owned by any package
```

That's because it's generated by the system at installation time, and later managed by the sysadmin (that is hopefully you) or NetworkManager.